# How is a DataGrid getting updated when I add an item to it through the ICollectionViews SourceCollection object

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, uicollectionview

I'm confused towards how my data grid is getting updated.

I have a datagrid defined like following:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" Style="{StaticResource DataGridDemoRowStyle}"     x:Name="grid"/>
```

The c  `Customers` object is a ICollectionView found in my viewmodel.

In my view model I populate the grid like so:

```
public ICollectionView Customers { get; private set; }

var _customers = new List<Customer>
                             {
                                 new Customer
                                     {
                                         FirstName = "Christian",
                                         LastName = "Moser",
                                         Gender = Gender.Male,
                                         WebSite = new Uri("http://www.wpftutorial.net"),
                                         ReceiveNewsletter = true,
                                         Image = "Images/christian.jpg"
                                     },
                                 new Customer
                                     {
                                         FirstName = "Peter",
                                         LastName = "Meyer",
                                         Gender = Gender.Male,
                                         WebSite = new Uri("http://www.petermeyer.com"),
                                         Image = "Images/peter.jpg"
                                     },
                                 new Customer
                                     {
                                         FirstName = "Lisa",
                                         LastName = "Simpson",
                                         Gender = Gender.Female,
                                         WebSite = new Uri("http://www.thesimpsons.com"),
                                         Image = "Images/lisa.jpg"
                                     },
                                 new Customer
                                     {
                                         FirstName = "Betty",
                                         LastName = "Bossy",
                                         Gender = Gender.Female,
                                         WebSite = new Uri("http://www.bettybossy.ch"),
                                         Image = "Images/betty.jpg"
                                     },
};

Customers = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_customers);
```

This works as intended. I then decided to try and add to the collection under the assumption the grid would not get updated, but it does:

```
List<Customer> i = Customers.SourceCollection;
i.Add(new Customer() { FirstName = "Bobby" });
```

My question is, how is this updating the grid? I am not calling the `Refresh` method on the ICollectionView. I can only assume the INotifyCollectionChanged event gets invoked at some point by the ICollectionView.

My model does implement INotifyPropertyChanged, but I don't see how this would update the grid to add a new item, only update the current items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the sample like yours, but modified it a bit, and all works as expected - DataGrid is not updated. Here the code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ICollectionView customers;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        var _customers = new List<Customer>
        {
            // Fill collection
        };

        customers = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_customers);
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = customers;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var c = new Customer { FirstName = "The new", LastName = "The added" };
        // Note that cast is required, otherwise compilation error occurs.
        List<Customer> i = this.customers.SourceCollection as List<Customer>;
        i.Add(c);
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
    <Button Content="Click me" Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click" />
</Grid>
```

Target .net framework is 4.5, but I think this is not so important.

It means that you have missed the detail. In your scenario you can add event handler for the [CollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.collectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event of your [ICollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview(v=vs.110).aspx) instance, and here you can understand the root cause of such behavior.